# Angular2 - Filtering list of objects. Empty results list even with a true comparison

Tags: angular, typescript

Let `Reference` be a class like this:

```
export class Reference {
    id : number;
    code : string;
    label : string;

    constructor(id : number, code : string, label : string {
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

And let's have a component who uses this `Reference` type, having an array of Reference `dataList` and another Reference `selectedReference`, which would be equal to one of the elements of the array (**equal meaning same property values**, not meaning same object). I would like to obtain the element in the array whose property `id` is equal to that one of `selectedReference`, so I filter the list. Here's the class' code:

```
export class filterExample {
    private dataList = Array<Reference>(); 
    private selectedValue : Reference = new Reference(2, 'R2', 'Reference 2');

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() { 
        for (let i : number = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            let reference : Reference = new Reference(i, `R${i}`, `Reference ${i}`);
            this.dataList.push(reference);
        }
        let element = this.dataList.filter((item : Reference) => {
            console.log(item.id === this.selectedValue.id);
            item.id === this.selectedValue.id;
        });    
        console.log(element);
    };
}
```

I expect to obtain in the console output the values `false`, `true`, `false`, and a list with only one element (the second one of the list, that one with an `id` whose value is 2). I would only expect to obtain an empty list if the values of the filtering comparison where `false`, `false`, `false`. However, the console output is:

```
false
true
false
[]
```

Well, I tried to make it simpler by doing:

```
let element = this.dataList.filter((item : Reference) => {
    console.log(item.id;
    item.id === 2;
});     
console.log(element);
```

The console output now says:

```
1
2
3
[]
```

Even if I do something silly as:

```
let element = this.dataList.filter((item : Reference) => {
    true;
});     
console.log(element);
```

The result is also an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything from your predicate function:

```
return item.id === this.selectedValue.id;
 ^-- add this.
```

You may only omit the return if you don't have a block, but an expression after the arrow. In that case only, the return is implicit:

```
this.dataList.filter(item  => item.id === this.selectedValue.id);
```

Also, filtering an array returns an array. Not the first element accepted by the predicate. So it should be

```
let element = this.dataList.filter(item => item.id === this.selectedValue.id)[0];
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you, I didn't know about the non implicit return in a block :)